# R - looping over one data frame with a function that operates on another data frame

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have a dataframe df1 which I wish to loop over by row, such that I can use it to update another dataframe, df2.

I take each row of df1 and use a user-defined function to update df2:

```
updateDF2 <- function (row_of_df1, df2) {
  # do something to df2 conditional on df1's columns
  assign('df2',df2,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Note the "assign" above updates df2. 
To test the user-defined function updateDF2, I took out a random row from df1 and assigned it to a new vector. I then call updateDF2 with the new vector and df2 as arguments. This has consistently worked with no issue.

It's the looping that I have problem with. I get error messages

> Error in row_of_df1$Column_of_condition: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

when I use

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) updateDF2(row_of_df1=x, df2=df2))
```

The same error occurs when I use

```
apply(df1[1,], 1, function(x) updateDF2(row_of_df1=x, df2=df2))
```

But if I use

```
new_vector <- df1[1,]
updateDF2(new_vector, df2)
```

there would be no error. What's the difference here?

Since individual rows of df1 works with the user-defined function, do I need to explicitly write a loop over rows of df1, or can I use one of the `apply` family commands to make it work?

Comment: The difference is probably in the code you did not provide.  Did you try it with `lapply`?  `apply` coerces data frames to matrices and does not coerce them back.  This could be the problem.  Also, you could try.  Try `lapply(df1, updateDF2, rowofDF1 = new_vector)`

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven. I'm looping over a dataframe, not a vector. Lapply as I understand applies to looping over a vector but not a dataframe. Two columns from each row of df1 is needed for the updateDF2 function; that's why I need to loop over df1, not just one column of it. In any case, what apply or lapply return do not matter to me. I just need to use a loop to update df2.

Comment: To make this work, I would need to use each row as an element to loop over. Not columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide *any* data, or any meaningful code, this is just a guess.

The `apply(...)` function coerces its first argument to a matrix and processes that row-wise (if the second argument is 1). So the rows that are passed to `FUN` are atomic vectors, not rows of a data frame. You can see this as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10), z=rpois(10,4))
class(df[1,])
#[1] "data.frame"
apply(df[1,],1,class)
#         1 
# "numeric"
```

In your function `updateDF2(...)`, you are probably referring to the elements of `row_of_df1` as, e.g., `row_of_df1$A`, etc., where `A` is the name of a column in `df1`. This will not work with an atomic vector. You could use `row_of_df1["A"]`, or `row_of_df1[1]` for example, but you cannot use the `$` operator.

You should also be aware that there are other problems with using `apply(...)`. Since it coerces the first argument to a matrix, and by definition all elements in a matrix must have the same data type, if `df1` has any columns of type `character`, *the whole matrix will be coerced to `character`*.

Comment: Thanks @jlhoward. This explains the error code. If you know of a way to loop through df1 to update df2 using the "apply" family, please let me know. The columns of df1 are of different types, including `factor`. I'm currently using an explicit for loop. It's slow.

Comment: yeah this doesnt really provide a solution :(  @MichM - did you ever figure it out?